# Grizzly server index page not working

Tags: java, grizzly

I have this server setup and route code.

```
package net.randohinn.neo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.Request;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.Response;

public class Main {

    public static HttpServer webServer;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        webServer = HttpServer.createSimpleServer();
        webServer.getServerConfiguration().setName("Neo CMS");
        webServer.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(
                new HttpHandler() {
                    public void service(Request request, Response response) throws Exception {
                        final SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", Locale.US);
                        final String date = format.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                        response.setContentType("text/plain");
                        response.setContentLength(date.length());
                        response.getWriter().write(date);
                    }
                },
                "/");
        try {
            webServer.start();
            Thread.currentThread().join();
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

If I now go to localhost:8080, it tells me that the resource for path / does not exist :( Seems like it can't detect the handler for the front page.. What could be wrong here? Changing the path in the Handler to `/time` for example, works fine.

Comment: @Sebas Doesn't work :(

Comment: Change         //webServer = HttpServer.createSimpleServer();
        //webServer.getServerConfiguration().setName("Neo CMS");
 webServer = new HttpServer();
        NetworkListener nl = new NetworkListener("Neo CMS", "localhost", 8080);
        webServer.addListener(nl);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing 
    //webServer = HttpServer.createSimpleServer();
    //webServer.getServerConfiguration().setName("Neo CMS");

```
webServer = new HttpServer();
NetworkListener nl = new NetworkListener("Neo CMS", "localhost", 8080);
webServer.addListener(nl);
```